# How to get data from html response after GET request

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, reactjs, request

I'm trying to get data from a request to make this through a NASA page, but i find with some difficulties to the moment when this request return the information.

First, ingress the *longitude* and *latitude* in this page, https://eosweb.larc.nasa.gov/sse/RETScreen/, but the response is a `HTML` page camplete with the data.

I want to know, how get the data in the table when the response render.

#### ingress the data

[image: image 1]

#### response

[image: image 2]

from the previous image, I would like to get the data from the column with the name of **Daily solar radiation - horizontal**

i'm work with `React`, `Javascript` and `Node`.

Answer (score 2):

Sumbit url of NASA link is return HTML with data not providing any json cause it is not rest api.
Use url to get data without html in json format

https://api.nasa.gov/api.html#genelab

and find your api